# I want to display different background to mobile devices Opencart

Tags: html, css, background, stylesheet, opencart

I'm working on a website right now and I designed a background that goes perfectly for all desktop users. Now I want instead of showing mobile users my /bg.jpg I want to show them /bg2.jpg or a solid color. How I do that? Heres the code from the stylesheet:

```
body{background:url('../image/bg.jpg');};font-size: 100.01%; font-family:tahoma, helvetica, sans-serif;}
```

Thanks Alot!

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can use media query, where you can write style for different device

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/

Answer (score 0):

Simply put if you wanna go the responsive way its as simple as to add in the end of your css file this piece of code

```
@media only screen and (max-width:960px){body{background:url('../image/bg2.jpg');}}
```

max-width is the maximum width of the screen that you need to this code to work for, also for this to work correcty you need to have spesified a correct meta viewport tag.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

for example.